# How to Convert Mathematica Notebooks to PDF's?

Tags: export, notebooks, options, conversion

My book is done. I'm left with twenty seven (27) Mathematica Notebooks (.nb's) How do I convert these notebooks to the pdf format? How do I combine all twenty seven (27) pdfs into a single pdf? Thanks for reading this!

Comment: ... or pdftk, from the command line

Answer (score 5):

Put all the notebooks into one, then export as PDF.  You can add in page breaks via the Insert menu: (insert) Page Break.

```
nb = NotebookOpen["/Users/chris/Documents/notebook.nb"];
Export[FileNameJoin[{$InitialDirectory, "output.pdf"}], nb]
```

You can modify layout in advance.  This setting persists only for the session.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
  PrintingOptions -> {"PrintingMargins" -> {{45, 43}, {17, 31}},
    "FirstPageHeader" -> False, "FirstPageFooter" -> False,
    "RestPagesHeader" -> False, "RestPagesFooter" -> False,
    "Magnification" -> 1}];
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is a bit over my head. Could you please specify a file path assuming my notebooks are in a folder on my Desktop (Windows 10 Pro)?

Comment: In a new session window run the following:  `nb = NotebookOpen["C:\\Users\\HenryB\\Desktop\\folder\\notebook.nb"];`  `Export["C:\\Users\\HenryB\\Desktop\\folder\\output.pdf", nb, "PDF"]`